# Is it possible to get the latitude and longtitude value for 15mts once?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

Am trying for long Days.But still i am trouble to get the latitude and longtitude value.My Goal is to get the latitude and longtitude value for 15mts once.am searching and trying follow links
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/find-current-location-in-android-gps.html

http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/

while adding this line i got error like this [Is it possible to get the latitude and longtitude value for 15mts once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819497/is-it-possible-to-get-the-latitude-and-longtitude-value-for-15mts-once/8820353#8820353)

**Error update**

```
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011): Error parsing response: 
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011): org.json.JSONException: Value <HTML><HEAD> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.google.GenieClient.sendGenieSearchRequest(GenieClient.java:509)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.google.GenieClient.executeGenieRequest(GenieClient.java:476)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.google.GenieClient.query(GenieClient.java:205)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.google.GenieClient.queryInternal(GenieClient.java:165)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at com.android.quicksearchbox.google.GoogleSource.getSuggestions(GoogleSource.java:120)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at com.android.quicksearchbox.google.GoogleSource.getSuggestions(GoogleSource.java:35)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at com.android.quicksearchbox.QueryTask.run(QueryTask.java:62)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
01-08 18:05:05.797: WARN/QSB.SuggestionProvider(2011):     at com.android.quicksearchbox.util.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(PriorityThreadFactory.java:45)
```

Comment: I think with the use of LocationManager you can get latitue and longitude. But still if you are not able to get it then check that you have GPS is on in the device. Second things is with the use of Location you can get distance between two latitude and longitude. Please check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,15, locationListener);
```